# Convert a PHP file into HTML file and hide a link after the convert is done

Tags: php, html, converters

As mentioned in my question: I have a php file that generate some data from the database.
I want to hide the link saying : Preview
This is my code in the php file :

```
<?php
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != "theme.html"){
    echo "<a href='theme.html' target='_blank' class='button'>Preview</a>";
}else{
    echo"";
}
?>
```

I successed converting  the php file into html file using this code:

```
file_put_contents('theme.html', ob_get_clean());
```

But the problem is It still show the "Preview" Link
How can I do to hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you echo the Preview link after `ob_get_clean()`, then the link will not be fetched by the output buffer.

```
<?php
ob_start();
// output that you want to save to file.

$file = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('theme.html', $file);

echo $file;

if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != "theme.html"){
    echo "<a href='theme.html' target='_blank' class='button'>Preview</a>"
}
```

Assuming this is what you meant...